# SubMenu Layout Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, menu, icons

I have read that submenus in Android do not support icons. I was wondering if this has changed, or if there is a similar way to produce a "submenu" that does support icons?

Currently This is My Submenu:
[image]

Here Is the XML File For It:

```
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
        android:title="Share With Facebook"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_facebook" />

    <item android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
        android:title="Share With Twitter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_twitter" />         
</menu>
```

I want it to look like this (If you have any ideas I would appreciate hearing them!):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own dialog instead of the submenu, and make it look any way you want.

Comment: How would I go about making one that looks like the above, and one that I could have start a different Activity if they clicked "Facebook" of "Twitter" ??

Comment: I would guess you put a ListView in a dialog, with each entry containing an icon and the text. Handle the onListItemClick event and start the activity you want.

Comment: Read the docs about dialogs and also about listviews. Dialogs in Android are a bit irritating (the entire framework is trying, to say the least), but once you get the hang of it, it's torelable...

Comment: A good starting point would be to read the [custom dialog example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) on the developer website.