# Custom SubMenu in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, menu, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SubMenu Layout Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274791/submenu-layout-android)

Is there anyway to make the following submenu look like the second (photoshopped) image?

Currently This is My Submenu:
[image]

Here Is the XML File For It:

```
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"
        android:title="Share With Facebook"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_facebook" />

    <item android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"
        android:title="Share With Twitter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_twitter" />         
</menu>
```

I want it to look like this (If you have any ideas I would appreciate hearing them!):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try some thing like this: 
1. Create class to store your item types

```
public final class AccountTypesProvider {
  public static List<AccountType> accountTypes = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
      new AccountType(AccountType.TWITTER_ACCOUNT, "Twitter", R.drawable.ic_menu_twitter),
      new AccountType(AccountType.FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT, "Facebook", R.drawable.ic_menu_facebook)     
  ));
}
```

2.Create ListAdapter

```
public final class AccountsTypesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AccountType> {
  private Activity context;
  private List<AccountType> accountTypes;
  public AccountsTypesListAdapter(Activity context, List<AccountType> accountTypes) {
    super(context, R.layout.select_account_item, accountTypes);   
    this.context = context;
    this.accountTypes = accountTypes;
  }  
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_account_item, parent, false);    
    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
    label.setText(accountTypes.get(position).title);    
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon_item);
    icon.setImageResource(accountTypes.get(position).bigIconId);
    return row;
  }
}
```

3.Layout for your adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10px">      <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_item"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                 <TextView android:id="@+id/text_item" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="10px"
                   android:paddingTop="5px" android:textStyle="bold" 
                   android:textColor="#000000"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
```

4.And your dialog

```
public static void showSelectAccountTypeDialog(Activity context, String title, OnClickListener dialogListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setAdapter(new AccountsTypesListAdapter(context, AccountTypesProvider.accountTypes), dialogListener);
    builder.create().show();
  }
```

This code was taken from [here](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android/103347/)

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is the context menus do not support icons.

The good news is you can do something about it, but it takes more work. You can follow [this article](http://www.tanisoft.net/2010/09/android-context-menu-with-icon.html) which explains the steps needed, or you can take the easy way and use a library like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/).